# How to run Angular 2 app without browser-sync and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, browser-sync

I have created an angular2 app with typescript. I am using Angular2 Routes for routing.
Using lite-server to start my angular2 app, it is working fine and routing properly if page is refreshed.

**ISSUE::**

But once i deployed the ts-compiled code to my domain which uses http-server to serve the files, it stop routing properly.

Whenever I refresh my page on my domain([blog.jyotirmaysenapati.com](http://blog.jyotirmaysenapati.com)), it shows below thing::

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /blog/new was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

Please help on this as i do not want to have node support in my domain. So how can i run it properly without the help of node and browser-sync??

Is it possible in first case??

> I am using latest version of angular2 framework.
>
> Anyone can see my code [here](https://github.com/jyotirmay123/myblog_1.0/tree/master/UI).

Comment: Using relative path inside your code ? In index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp-connect which provide fallback option :-

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect',function() {
    connect.server({
        root: '',
        port: 8080,
        fallback: 'index.html',
        middleware: function(connect) {
        return [connect()
            .use('/node_modules', connect.static('./node_modules')), connect()
            .use('/app', connect.static('./dist'))
        ];
    }
});
})
```

Comment: No, I think you did not understand my requirement. Gulp itself need node environment to run. I do not have luxury of node in my domain. So I want pure javascript built system where i can run angular2 app without node, gulp, browser-sync.